# Different point markers in SciChart

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

It is possible to have different point markers on the same dataseries? Maybe some of the points should use for example the Cross point marker, maybe other points should use the Ellipse point marker and so on. Is there any solution for this?

I am using SciChart Version 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no sure for v3.5 but I think you can derive from `SciChart.Charting.Visuals.PointMarkers.BasePointMarker` and implement `protected override void DrawInternal(..)`. In your implementation you can check if the current point is within a specified limit for x/y axis and then decide which marker to use.

You can then use the point marker API to set the custom pointmarker in XAML or code. See also: https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/webframe.html#Point%20Marker%20API%20-%20BaseRenderableSeries.Pointmarker.html